# Open a fullscreen window on 2nd monitor with SFML?

Tags: c++, c, windows, sfml

Is there a way to open a full screen window with [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/) on a 2nd monitor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is no. Here's a quote from a different part of that site:

> SFML doesn't explicitely manage multiple monitors. As a consequence, you won't be able to choose which monitor a window appears on, and you won't be able to create more than one fullscreen window. This should be improved in a future version.

Comment: Is there any change with the recently released SFML 2?

Comment: @danijar, not sure, but I don't think so, since I was using SFML2 pre and it did not have it. I will check back here when I have tested it again.

Comment: @PajeetRamahari-Mawari-Kulmini As of the current version, 2.4, this has not changed:

https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/window-window.php